# Derivative of a Fourier transform in $L^2$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If $f$ is a Schwartz function, then $(\widehat{\partial_x f})(\xi)=(-i\xi\widehat{f}(\xi))$ ([https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Man-wah-Wong-ebook/dp/B00W8OO57A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W8OO57A))

If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Does $\widehat{\partial_x f}(\xi)=(-i\xi\widehat{f}(\xi))(x)$ also hold?

Comment: Yes, in the sense of distributions